# 'Or' not working with strings in if conditional after user input

Tags: string, input, conditional-statements

So, I'm a noob, and after 2 hours of searching online, I can't find an example of my failed code ANYWHERE, nor can I find answers related to my specific dilemma, which is surprising since it seems like it would be a fairly common conceptual mistake.

Here's my code:

name = input('Who are you?')

if name == **"Mike" or "mike":**

```
print('Hi',name,', nice to see you!')
```

else:

```
print("I don't know you.")
```

All I want the program to do is print the 'Hi', name... statement if the user inputs Mike or mike. I'm not wanting to just change the case, but in the future I'd like to use 'Mike' or 'Susie' (or something like that).

Right now it's always printing the 'Hi', name... statement no matter what I input. If I delete one of the names, then it works.

Can someone tell me:
a) Why it doesn't work the way I tried coding this, and
b) What would be the easiest and/or most efficient way to code this, especially if I want to increase the number of inputs that are accepted?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

You did not give a programming language, but your problem is universal across all languages.

You are trying to cram a colloqial sentence into computer logic and it fails. The computer does not understand your human shortcuts, it needs it spelled out:

This is what you would say to another human:

```
if they are Mike OR Susie
```

This is what you **mean** by that:

```
if their name is Mike OR their name is Susie
```

And this is *exactly* what you need to tell the computer:

```
if name == "Mike" OR name == "Susie"
```

Please note that a good language/IDE combination with a good confiuration will throw you a lot of warnings and errors when you *compile*, it won't even let you run your colloqial human logic. If yours does not, you need to tune it up to assist you better and if it cannot be tuned up, you may want to think about using a better IDE or a better language in general.

Comment: The language was Python. That makes perfect sense now that someone's explained it like that!
Thanks so much for the quick response!